# How to get rid of shadow from transparent area when background lighting only in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I have a scene with a a few planes that have a transparency texture (alpha map) set up. Lighting is done with environment texture only.

[image: Simple scene with background lighting, transparent areas cast shadows]

Problem is that with 0 diffuse bounces I get shadow action from the planes even at the transparent areas. I am looking for an Cycles only (no compositing!) way to get rid of the shadow action with 0 diffuse bounces.

For comparison, change lighting from background to sun (add sun, remove any input from world output surface, or set background strength to 0.0), and you'll see there is no shadow action from transparent areas of the planes.

[image: Simple scene with sun lighting, transparent areas don't cast shadows]

Comment: My explanation: HDRI is like every pixel is light emitor. That means you will get shadows around the object. Try to use pole object, how it behaves in same situation. There should be shadows ale around that pole. Problem is with your HDRI, which has not any source of hard shadows. I would try to remove shadow casting from HDRI and tried to mimic shadows with sun light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking around in IRC it turns out this is actually a bug with background light + transparent BSDF.

Reported https://developer.blender.org/T44599